# Auto sequential numbering of (save) filenames in GUI dialogs?

Tags: files, filenames, gui

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and often I user PrtScn (Print Screen) key to get a screenshot; then I get a dialog like:

[image: gnome-screenshot]

Here, by default you get a filename `Screenshot.png` as default; however, if a file of that name already exists, then `gnome-screenshot` will do automatic sequential numbering of the filename, and suggest `Screenshot-1.png`.

Now, let's say I don't want `Screenshot` as the base of the filename, but something like `mypic`. Is there a way that I enter this filename in some format - say, `mypic%03d.png` - such that, upon save, the system will check what is the biggest number of existing `mypic*` files (say `mypic010.png`), and then would autoincrement that number to get the "expanded" filename of the file to be saved (which in this example would be `mypic011.png`)?

Note that here, I just mention `gnome-screenshot` as an example; I'd be interested to use something like this from all and any GUI file save dialogs: for instance, if I have a text file in Geany, and upon "Save As" I enter `/tmp/mytext%03d.txt`, then the system would check the final existing number of existing `mytext*.txt` file in the `/tmp` directory, autoincrement by one, and save the file with that number in the `/tmp` directory.

Is there any standard that does this? If not, are there alternative workarounds? If I was in the shell command line, I could just do a script to calculate autoincrement numeric suffixes - and then use something like `$(get-next-num.sh /tmp/mytext%03d.txt)` instead of the filename; but since here the problem is with GUI dialogs, I doubt that any and all GUI dialogs would interprert `$(get-next-num.sh /tmp/mytext%03d.txt)` as a directive to run this as `bash` code in a subshell...

Comment: This stuff is most likely hard-coded in each app implementation of [GtkFileChooser](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) (see `gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name ()`) so I'd say there's no way to change it unless you patch the source code.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to setup a generic background process that listens for new files with well-defined names, and automatically renames them. 
You can use `inotifywait` to efficiently watch a directory like `~/Desktop` for new files being created (specifically, closed after open for write), and then rename that file if it is `Screenshot.png` to the next free `mytext999.txt` file. Here's an example. Most of the code is the `template` function to find the next free filename, which is not the object of the question.

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418088/119298
# auto rename files when they are written to in watched directory
template(){
        local file=$1 max=$2 suffix=$3 pat last next
        pat="$file${max//9/[0-9]}$suffix"
        for last in $pat; do : ; done
        if [ "$last" = "$pat" ]
        then    next=${max//9/0}  # no files, start from 0
        else    last="${last:${#file}:${#max}}"
                [ "$last" = "$max" ] && return 1
                printf -v next "%0${#max}d" $((10#$last+1))
        fi
        newfile="$file$next$suffix"
        [ ! -e "$newfile" ]
}

cd ~/Desktop/
inotifywait -m -e close_write ~/Desktop/ |
while read dir event file
do      case $file in
        Screenshot.png) template mypic 999 .png || exit
                        mv "$file" "$newfile" ;;
        esac
done
```